# Will Django always consider an Emoji as 1 character long?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, emoji

I'm making a Post Reaction model that uses emojis as reactions, and at this point I'm not mapping them to Choices, but instead inserting the utf-8 value (e.g. ) directly to the Database (Postgres) as a CharField instance.
This made me think which value should I use to the max_length of this field. I know Rust will take emojis as 1 char long, but I'm not sure about how python or Postgres will react.

Comment: Easy to test, isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly, since we have more than 1000 different emojis...

Comment: The emoji of country flags count as two, so `len('')` is `2`.

Comment: Oh, I'll leave some slack on this than, maybe 4-5 chars, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length limit of a `character varying` column in PostgreSQL is always measured in characters, not in bytes. So emojis will count to the length limit either as 1 (if they are a single character) or as more (if they include a [zero width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)).